# Requesting posts of a facebook group

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-group

I am looking to create a product that retrieves the posts of a public facebook group (viewable to non-members) and analyse that data based on (from necessary to useful) posts (as strings to be processed), like count, different reaction count and possible geotag data. I am confused by the process of application, as I cannot use the group api without already having an approved app and such - is there a way to retrieve and work on data in python/java/js without actually creating an app, for testing purposes?

Comment: there is NOTHING you can do without creating an app. did you try with a group you manage? please add what you have tried so far (research, code, ...)